# change class active in the navigation top menu bar for bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm having issue with changing the active class when clicking different links in the top navigation bar in bootstrap. There are many posts related to this issue in the forum but I tried most of the suggestions there. What worked for me was the active class changes when clicking different links when I use the jquery code below which I copied from one of the posts found in this forum:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.nav > li').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('ul.nav > li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
  });
});
```

This allows me to change the active class when clicking from one link to another. However, what doesn't work now is that it seems to be unable to read the content from the a href.

If I comment out the line `e.preventDefault();`, everything works again in that it loads the content based on the link specified in `a href="link_3"` but the class active doesn't work any longer. for example there are link_1, link_2 and link_3. If I click link_3, it loads up the page for link_3 but the active class goes back to link_1.

I'm not sure what else to try out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: through `href` you mean when the page loads for particular section and class do not move to the appropriate `li`?

Answer (score 0):

Your question shows that you have just started working with Web technologies. The href in `<a href=""></a>` is defining the page to go to when the link clicked. However when a link is clicked the whole page reload so your Javascript/jQuery changes doesn't have any effect anymore.

When you call `e.preventDefault();` you stop the request to go to the new page specified in href and then you don't reload the page and your Javascript works.

You can't do both of them at the same time. What I'd suggest is to remove all of your JS/jQuery code and just open each page (link_1, link_2, link_3) HTML and add the active class to the correct element in each page.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use jQuery You can do this just using bootsrap `active` class

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav > .active > a:focus {
    color: #BFDD19 !important;
    background-color: transparent;
    font-weight: 700;
}
```